# ERROR [org.apache.velocity] ResourceManager : unable to find resource 'layout.vm' in any resource loader

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, velocity, resource-loading

MyController.java:

```
@Controller
public class ForemanController {

    @RequestMapping({"/index", "/"})
    public ModelAndView home(Model model){

        Map<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
        // .. fill map
        return new ModelAndView("index", "map", map);
    }   
}
```

ServletInitializer.java:

```
public class ServletInitializer extends AbstractAnnotationConfigDispatcherServletInitializer {

    @Override
    protected Class<?>[] getRootConfigClasses() {
        return new Class<?>[0];
    }

    @Override
    protected Class<?>[] getServletConfigClasses() {
        return new Class<?>[]{AppConfig.class};
    }

    @Override
    protected String[] getServletMappings() {
        return new String[]{"/"};
    }
}
```

AppConfig.java:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
@ComponentScan(basePackages = {"com.my"})
public class AppConfig {

    @Bean
    public VelocityConfigurer velocityConfig(){
        VelocityConfigurer velocityConfig = new VelocityConfigurer();
        velocityConfig.setResourceLoaderPath("/");
        return velocityConfig;
    }

    @Bean
    public VelocityLayoutViewResolver viewResolver(){
        VelocityLayoutViewResolver viewResolver = new VelocityLayoutViewResolver();
        viewResolver.setCache(true);
        viewResolver.setPrefix("/WEB-INF/views/");
        viewResolver.setSuffix(".vm");
        return viewResolver;
    }

}
```

index.vm under WEB-INF/views:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
    <title>foreman</title>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
</head>
<body>
    hello world!
</body>
</html>
```

I deploy to Wildfly, deployment successful, hit the home page with 'localhost:8080/myapp' and I get `Internal Server Error`:

```
2016-03-11 01:48:58,844 ERROR [org.apache.velocity] (default task-11) ResourceManager : unable to find resource 'layout.vm' in any resource loader.
```

I see no mention of 'layout' anywhere in my project. Where is this coming from?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is default behavior of `VelocityLayoutViewResolver` in your bean `viewResolver` to search for a template `layout.vm`.

`layout.vm` is expected to serve as a frame or wrapper around the views determined by your controller. That's very handy, because you don't need to bother about how a special view and your general HTML page are merged.

Please see this for example this [tutorial](http://vozis.blogspot.de/2012/07/spring-mvc-and-velocity-webapp.html) (start at 'Creating templates') and this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34329147/how-to-use-velocitylayoutviewresolver-in-spring-webmvc-with-velocity/34778030#34778030) for details.

Comment: thanks I wish important conventions would be made clearer in official docs. I don't see layout.vm explicitly defined as such anyway on the velocity site.

Comment: Little misunderstanding here - this isn't original Velocity but Spring. Here is the [doc](http://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/2.0.x/api/org/springframework/web/servlet/view/velocity/VelocityLayoutViewResolver.html).